# Image is overwriting in local Folder using multer in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I am trying to upload image in Local folder as well as saving the image name in MongoDB.

```
var uploadDir=__dirname+'/uploads';
 var images=Date.now()+'.jpg';
var storage=multer.diskStorage({

    destination:function(request, file, callback){
        callback(null, uploadDir);
        },
        filename:function(request, file, callback){
            console.log(file);
            callback(null, images);
            }
    });
    var upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('image');
```

Above is the multer configuration code. The problem is that while I insert an image then it is saving successfully in local folder but again I save another image then the new image is overwriting the previous image in folder. But in MongoDB images name are differents.

Comment: Upload first time then rename it(rename it where you are saving image using multer) with something like old-<name>.jpg then upload other image and check that image uploaded with name is same as the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added images value as Date.now on top the file which will executes once at the time of loading .

Try below code.

var uploadDir=__dirname+'/uploads';

var storage= multer.diskStorage({

```
destination:function(request, file, callback){
    callback(null, uploadDir);
    },
    filename:function(request, file, callback){
        var images = '.jpg';
        console.log(file);
        images += Date.now()+images;
        callback(null, images);
        }
});
var upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('image');
```

Comment: hey....I used user code, now images are not overwriting but now the images rename is something like ".jpg1464689634067.jpg1464689686302.jpg1464689634067.jpg1464689845313.jpg1464689634067.jpg1464689686302.jpg1464689634067" I mean to say that now the image name is repeating again and again.

Comment: just put  filename:function(request, file, callback){
        images = '.jpg';
        images += Date.now()+images;
        callback(null, images);
        }   then it will works

Comment: I replaced images+=Date.now()+images with images=Date.now()+images now its working fine.